# Node Js MongoDB add multiple datalines

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb

Hi need some help using Node Js to add data to MongoDB.

My route looks like this

```
    app.get('/article/:id/add', function(req, res) {
    Listing.findOne(req.params.id, function (err, p) {

        if (err) throw err;

        res.render('', {});

    });
});
```

my Schema like this

```
    article: {
    ownerid     : String,
    name        : String,
    imagename   : String,
    interessted_user : {
        id  :   String
    }
}
```

If a User Hit the "Add" button at the frond end, Ajax execute get /article/:id/add.

How can Add multiple Users who are interested in this article to MongoDB.

It should look something like this.

```
     article: {
        ownerid     : String,
        name        : String,
        imagename   : String,
        interessted_user : {
            id  :   123456789098765432123456789,
765432123456765432345676543,
234567654321345678765432234
        }
    }
```

So later on i want to show the owner of this article all the interested users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `array`, so the schema becomes:

```
{
    article: {
       ownerid     : String,
       name        : String,
       imagename   : String,
       interessted_user : Array
    }
}
```

Then a row should look like this:

```
article: {
        ownerid     : String,
        name        : String,
        imagename   : String,
        interessted_user : [123456789098765432123456789, 765432123456765432345676543, 234567654321345678765432234]
}
```